# How to paginate in GCS when using GAE Python GCS Client Library for access ?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

GCS = Google Cloud Storage
GAE = Google App Engine

If there is a huge number of files in a given directory (emulated directory since no real ones exist), how do I manage :

1. Listing all files for some processing in my GAE Python code ?
2. Sort in descending order of file name ( in directories where all files
   could be converted to numbers ) ?

[listbucket](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#listbucket)() mentions about pagination but does not elaborate. I do not understand how to paginate using [listbucket](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#listbucket)().

I used [listbucket](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#listbucket)() as shown below :

```
import cloudstorage as gcs 
:: 
bucket_name             = os.environ.get ('BUCKET_NAME', app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name ())


gcs_list_obj            = gcs.listbucket ('/' + bucket_name + '/dir_1/dir_2/', delimiter="/") 

# ITERATE THROUGH YEAR DIRECTORIES TO GET THE HIGHEST YEAR DIRECTORY NAME VALUE. 
year_list   = [] 
for item in gcs_list_obj: 
    # EACH "ITEM" WOULD BE A DIRECTORY REPRESENTING TIMESTAMP YEAR. 
    if item.is_dir: 
        # IT IS A DIRECTORY. 
        filename    = item.filename 
        # EXTRACT YEAR FROM ABSOLUTE FILENAME. 
        year_name   = "" 
        counter     = len (filename) - 2 # START AT SECOND LAST CHARACTER. 
        while (filename[counter]!="/"): 
            year_name   = filename[counter] + year_name 
            counter     = counter - 1 
        # COLLECT ALL YEAR VALUES. 
        year_list.append ( int (year_name) ) 

# SORT THEM IN DESCENDING ORDER. 
year_list   = sorted (year_list, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cloudstorage.listbucket` returns an **iterator** so you can "paginate" by only getting and showing N items at a time (e.g with `itertools.islice` from the standard Python library).

However it yields object info (instances of `https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/gcsfilestat_class`) strictly in alphabetical order, and there's no way to change that (in particular to invert the order, as you seem to desire).

If you **must** show the objects in some different order, you'll have to forego actual pagination -- make a list in memory then sort it, as you're doing now (then you can **present** that sorted list in a "paginated" way of course, but meanwhile it's taken all that memory).

Feel free to open a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list of course -- there is currently no feature to have GCS sort things anyway **but** alphabetical ascending order by object name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanatory answer. I would try our the iterator part once before marking this answer as accepted. As suggested by you, I have opened a [Feature Request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11715). Appreciate your help and time.